# In caffeinated Laravel Module, how can I access the lang files

Tags: laravel-5

I have created a lang file under resources/Lang/en for a module say Room
I am using caffeinated modules

The file itself is Room.php

```
return [
   'deleted' => 'Room has been deleted successfully'
];
```

Now I am trying to use lang through

```
trans('room::room.deleted')
```

but I am not able to get translated string.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file in /resource/lang is minuscule.

Eg. room.php

Answer (score 0):

This is the path of variable in first image:

[image]

And then, is called this way in blade:

```
<p>@lang('adminpanel::auth.password')</p>
```